# How to create new attribute by combining existing 2 attribute in Weka?

Tags: weka

I am new to Weka and found there's only little document on the filter function.
Actually, I have 2 attribute i.e `profit`, `cost`. I would like to create a new attribute name `result` which compares `profit` and `cost` attributes and , for each row value, `result` label will be `gain` if `profit` > `cost`, otherwise the label will be 'loss'.

I am using Weka Explorer UI. And I tried `Copy` and `MergeTwoValue` filter but seems it can't do the comparison step. What would be the right step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a comparison is possible using the [MathExpression](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/MathExpression.html) filter as part of filter processing pipeline, using the `ifelse` construct. However, MathExpression does not allow you to use labels, but you can have an indicator label `0` or `1` to indicate whether gain or loss.

```
MultiFilter
|
+- Add  (we insert a new numeric attribute, all missing values)
|
+- ReplaceMissingWithUserConstant (MathExpression skips missing values, hence replacing them in our new attribute)
|
+- MathExpression (the actual comparison between the two attributes)
|
+- NumericToNominal (to turn the numeric 0/1 values into labels)
```

I will demonstrate how to construct this pipeline using the *bolts* UCI dataset, which has the following attributes:

```
1 RUN     numeric
2 SPEED1  numeric
3 TOTAL   numeric
4 SPEED2  numeric
5 NUMBER2 numeric
6 SENS    numeric
7 TIME    numeric
8 T20BOLT numeric
```

For this example, I want to compare `SENS` and `TIME`, creating an indicator whether `SENS > TIME`.

**MultiFilter**

The [MultiFilter](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/MultiFilter.html) instance combines all our sub-filters into a single filter setup. That way you can easily apply, extend it or use it within a [FilteredClassifier](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/FilteredClassifier.html) setup.

**Add**

First, we will add an attribute using the [Add](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Add.html) filter at index `8`, which will push the class attribute to position `9`, giving it the name `SENS>TIME` (you can give it any name you want):

```
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Add -N SENS>TIME -C 8
```

**ReplaceMissingWithUserConstant**

Next, we use the [ReplaceMissingValueUserConstant](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/ReplaceMissingWithUserConstant.html) filter to replace the missing values in our attribute (index `8`) with a dummy value, e.g., `-1`. This is unfortunately necessary, since `MathExpression` does not operate on missing values.

```
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.ReplaceMissingWithUserConstant -A 8 -R -1 -F "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss"
```

**MathExpression**

With the stage set, we can now use [MathExpression](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/MathExpression.html) to fill in our comparison using the expression `ifelse(A6>A7,1,0)`:

```
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.MathExpression -E ifelse(A6>A7,1,0) -V -R 8
```

If attribute `6` (`SENS`) is greater than attribute `7` (`TIME`), then insert a `1` otherwise a `0`.

**NumericToNominal**

With the [NumericToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericToNominal.html) filter we will turn the numeric indicators in our comparison attribute into nominal labels:

```
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal -R 8
```

**Bonus**

If you want to use the labels `gain`/`loss` instead of `1`/`0`, then you can add the [RenameNominalValues](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/RenameNominalValues.html) filter at the end of the pipeline.